# Frameless window for a browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

I am looking to develop an application which runs a simulator. There are three major stipulations:

1. the application needs to be cross platform (windows and linux) - which is why the browser idea appealed to me;
2. the window it opens must not have a toolbar and definitely no close, minimize buttons etc;
3. it must allow the user to resize the window.

I have been told that Webkit with a css and javascript website will allow me to meet the above criteria. I had also toyed with the idea of using QT. Which would be the best solution? Also I am not very familiar with webkit and was looking for some good tutorials online. Any useful links?

Comment: The control of how the browser looks might not be able to be controllable from a JavaScript point of view, but if you also have control of the computer in some way it might be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with developing a little bit in [Node.js](http://nodejs.org), I'd suggest you going with any of the following 2 packages:

- Node Webkit https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit
- AppJS http://appjs.org/ *(no longer maintained)*

They both allow you to create what you're trying to achieve while backed by the power of Webkit.

Comment: AppJS is dead. You might want to remove the link or maybe reorder them. node-webkit appears to be the winner these days.